# How do I distribute in-development iOS apps to a customer for in-process evaluation without releasing to appstore

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

We are developing an app specifically to a single customer's requirements and want to put it in the hands of their evaluation team (3 people) as we go along. Before we release the product, we'll be going with enterprise distro but we need to figure out this interim step.

Comment: This is called Adhoc distribution. There are plenty of Apple docs on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. The sources I've read said that Adhoc distro was not permissible to folks outside the organization, thus the question. We already have an enterprise account and the terms for that were very clear that we can only use this for internal folks. I've been looking for something on Apple's site that says an evaluation deployment for a customer review counts as "internal" but nothing I've seen supports this.

Comment: You didn't mention you were using an Enterprise account. Adhoc is normally used for testing. At least with non-Enterprice, you can use testers from anywhere. I don't know the rules of the Enterprise program.

Answer (score 0):

Get an iOS developer account for $99 and register the devices of those three people to your account.

Comment: We already have an enterprise account but neither enterprise nor developer accts allow for external distro.

Answer (score 0):

I use a company called testflight, they are at [testflightapp.com](http://www.testflightapp.com) They make it pretty easy to distribute an application to testers when you have an ios developer account.

Comment: We use TestFlight already for internal QA distribution but I don't believe that gets around Apple's prohibition of external distribution. I'm trying to conform to the letter of our agreement.

Answer (score 0):

At my company, we have the customer sign up for the $99 developer program and manage their own devices, then have them add our developers as developers (surprise), and make special builds for their devices.*

We also recently had a (larger) client sign up for an enterprise account so they could distribute our builds to their employees for testing w/o having to manage UDIDs.

Takes the ball out of your court, but it does seem to adhere to the Apple standards.

<sub>*: We frequently end up releasing these custom builds to the app store via the customer's developer account, which (IIRC) is also in line with Apple standards. If the app is branded by/exclusively for a given company, it makes sense.</sub>